# Redirecting using location.path()

Tags: angularjs

On first click of button it is redirecting to the specified location but clicking later it is redirected to login form. I'm totally stuck.. please help.

```
$scope.edit = function () {    
      $location.path('/Appointment');    
}    

$stateProvider.state('Appointment', {    
            url: '/Appointment',
            parent: 'common',
            templateUrl: 'templates/Appointment.html',
            controller: 'AppointmentCtrl'    
        });
```

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

Comment: issue might be at your `run` block or `AppointmentCtrl`. So add more code

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with a sample code snippet?

Comment: May be somewhere the url is added  with extra text. But not sure, once you show your code, then we can solve it

Comment: You can use `$window`  for example :  `$window.location.href = '/Appointment';`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$window` in angular.

for example

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('LoginCtrl', LoginCtrl);

    LoginCtrl.$inject = ['$window', 'loginSrv', 'notify'];

    function LoginCtrl($window, loginSrv, notify) {
        /* jshint validthis:true */
        var vm = this;
        vm.validateUser = function () {
             loginSrv.validateLogin(vm.username, vm.password).then(function (data) {          
                if (data.isValidUser) {    
                    $window.location.href = '/redirectpath';
                }
                else
                    alert('Login incorrect');
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

hope this helps .

Answer (score 0):

Try using $state.go() instead of `$location.path()`

```
$scope.edit = function () {    
      $state.go('Appointment');    
}
```

Comment: i tried using $state.go it is redirecting correctly on first click, later it is redirected to login

Comment: Seems like second time the state 'Appointment' is getting undefined and hence redirecting to your otherwise. Is the parent: 'common' in state object is really neccassary? Try removing parent: 'common' and see.